# Hiding Top Level List Items

Tags: css, html-lists

I am looking for a pure CSS solution to hide top level list items in an unordered list. For example:

- Top level item 1

  Top level item 2

  - Sub item 1

    Sub item 2

    Sub item 3

  Top level item 3

Becomes...

- Sub item 1

  Sub item 2

  Sub item 3

Initially I figured I this would be quite simple. I created a simple little example like so...

```
<ul>
  <li> Top level item 1
  <li> Top level item 2
  <ul>
    <li> Sub item 1
    <li> Sub item 2
    <li> Sub item 3
  </ul>
  <li> Top level item 3
</ul>
```

Styling it using something like...

```
.menu ul{
    display:none;
}
.menu ul li ul{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

...but it seems that if the parent ul is hidden then I can't show the child ul. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do what you want without requiring javascript and html changes in your structure is that way.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2SS9k/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you want is not possible with CSS as you know & you have tried but if you just want to do it anyway then below are some methods but i dont think it will fulfill your needs:

**Method 1**  http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/2SS9k/1/

```
ul > li {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  line-height: 1px;
}

ul > li > ul >li{
    text-indent: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```